# Can't transfer mysql data from one database to another

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to rework an old implementation of osCommerce and re-introduce data from the old database to the new one. I exported the data from the old tables using phpMyAdmin. When I tried to import them to the new database, I got a series of errors. I am simplifying the problem here to a single INSERT statement for the sake of clarity.

The statement is:

```
INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, 
                            `customers_id`, 
                            `entry_gender`,
                            `entry_company`, 
                            `entry_firstname`, 
                            `entry_lastname`, 
                            `entry_street_address`, 
                            `entry_suburb`, 
                            `entry_postcode`, 
                            `entry_city`, 
                            `entry_state`, 
                            `entry_country_id`, 
                            `entry_zone_id`) 
  VALUES (1, 1, 'm', '', 'Mary', 'Smith', 
          '1234 Pleasant Court', '', '67890',
          'Hometown', 'state', 123, 0);
```

When I try to import it from a file through phpMyAdmin I get an error: `“#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.”`

If I click the Edit button and resubmit the query, I get another error: `“#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'.”` The address_book_id field is the primary key in this table and is an auto-increment field.

Still in the edit screen, if I change the address_book_id value to NULL and resubmit, the query is accepted.

Thinking I had the issue resolved, I changed the address_book_id value in the import file to NULL and tried importing again. And again, I get the #1064 error. I immediately clicked edit. I made no edits to the statement but submitted it without change. This time, the statement was accepted.

It appears to be a problem with handling the address_book_id value in the downloaded data. I have hundreds of index values from numerous tables from the old database. Obviously, I don't want to have to change the index values and submit them one at a time.

I am working with phpMyAdmin 3.5.1. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: There is a typo - **VALUES** - not  **ALUES** -- NSERT INTO address_book (address_book_id, customers_id, entry_gender, entry_company, entry_firstname, entry_lastname, entry_street_address, entry_suburb, entry_postcode, entry_city, entry_state, entry_country_id, entry_zone_id) **ALUES** (1, 1, 'm', '', 'Mary', 'Smith', '1234 Pleasant Court', '', '67890', 'Hometown', 'state', 123, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Do it without the `address_book_id`. Apparently that one is the primary key which you can't simply copy from another table. The new ID should be assigned automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Johannes won't reassigning keys destroy any referential integrity between tables? This seems dangerous to me.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch : Reassign keys? - he is copying data from one table to another - the "other" table should already have it's own primary key, so if the key is an integer and already exists, there will be an error as described in the second paragraph of the question. If the original index value should be preserved, it shouldn't be copied to the primary key column, but in to another column that might still have to be created for this purpose (and which obviuosly should not be a unique key). The table structures (especially keys/IDs) isn't explained, so that's just what I suppose it looks like...

Comment: Maybe I phrased it poorly, but we're talking about the same thing. If another table references `address_book_id` and Tom Jones becomes 2 instead of 3 because it's now assigning new key IDs, the data gets all confused. Your comment about adding a new column is a great solution. Without seeing the table structure we're definitely guessing at this anyway.

Comment: I don't understand how adding an additional column to put the 'old' primary keys is going to do any good. Doesn't putting those values in, say, address_book_id_old mess up referential integrity? Also, I think some of the existing php code depends on those key values.  I am tempted to try turning off the primary keys and loading the documents, then try to turn the keys back on. Possible?  Here is the address_book table structure as a png image:  <img src="http://comechildrensing.com/address_book_structure.png" width="470" height="289">

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for a while, I think the best approach is to delete then recreate the tables. I tried this on two tables and was then able to upload my data, including the id fields without throwing any errors. The tables seem to be working OK.